# How to search for an element containing a particular text in all pages in a dynamic table in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I search for text and click on the button in a row which has the search string in a dynamic table using custom xpath :
`//div/span[contains(text(),'search string')]/parent::div/parent::td/following-sibling::td/button[@class='btton-clicked-on-table']")`

which works if the search string is on the first page.

Now, if the same string is on another page other than the first page then I get not found exception. So how do I search the same string in multiple pages of a dynamic table?

Comment: your question is not very clear to me. What exactly you mean by 'Now, how do I search the string in multiple pages in the table?' Please share relevant html as well.

Comment: For example:  I need to search for the GDPR text in all the pages and click on check box in this page https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues

Comment: Selenium interact with web page in same way a human does, it cannot find elements on other pages without visiting them. You will have to visit each page and then search for the element. In this case to make it easier you can set Per page results to 100 and now you have few pages to search element for.

Comment: I am not sure if its your requirement but you can also use filters such as 'Subject' and then search for issues contains 'GDPR'

Comment: In my real test page I dont have this ability to show the per page results

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to go to every page to find element unless someone else here have any solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah, as @theGuy suggested, you can either go through each pages until you find a text you're looking for or have the page show the maximum allowed results in the table, in this case 100.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample URL you provided, here's some quick code to do what you are looking for that you can adapt to the site you are working with.

```
String url = "https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues";
driver.navigate().to(url);

String searchTerm = "Tracker";
By searchTermLocator = By.xpath("//td[@class='subject']/a[contains(.,'" + searchTerm + "')]");
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(searchTermLocator);
while (links.size() == 0)
{
    // click Next
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next »")).click();
    // look for matches
    links = driver.findElements(searchTermLocator);
}

// match found, click it
links.get(0).click();
```

The search term I'm looking for is found on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to the find the element every time you moved to next/new page, also make sure you have proper wait before searching for element, try below

```
int pageCount=0; // count of pages
while(nextPageIsAvaialable)
{
    pageCount++;
    List<WebElement> checkBoxOf_searchText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/span[contains(text(),'search string')]/parent::div/parent::td/following-sibling::td/button[@class='btton-clicked-on-table']")); // use findElements --> to avoid NoSuchElementException
    if (!checkBoxOf_searchText.isEmpty()) 
     {
        checkBoxOf_searchText.get(0).click();
        System.out.println("Found on page number : "+ pageCount);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found on page number : "+ pageCount);
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpressionOfNextPage).click(); 
}
```